# A solution of $i\partial_t u=(-\Delta)^{\beta/2}u$ using Fourier transform.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I need to show that $$w(x,t)=\lambda^\frac{n}{2\beta}u(\lambda^{1/\beta}x-2\lambda^{1/\beta}x_0t, \lambda t)e^{i(x\cdot x_0-|x_0|^\beta t)},\quad n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$$ is solution of $$i\partial_t u=(-\Delta)^{\beta/2}u.$$

Here $\beta>0$ and $u=u(x,t)$. It is suggested to use Fourier transform, but since the Laplacian of this PDE is fractional order, I am not clear on how to approach this problem. I humbly request the help of an expert. Thanks partners.

Comment: Let say if $\beta =2$, can you show that $w$ is a solution by Fourier transform?

Comment: I do not see why the fact that the Laplacian changes something ... it is still defined as a Fourier multiplier so taking the Fourier transform of the equation is simple: $i\partial_t \widehat u(t,y) = |2\pi y|^\beta \widehat u(t,y)$ and now this is a simple separable ODE. Is it sufficient to unlock you?

Comment: @LL 3.14  After taking Fourier transform in space, an ODE results whose solution is 
$$\widehat{u}(\xi,t)=Ce^{-i|\xi|^\beta t},$$ If we take inverse transform to both sides, $$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\widehat{u}(\xi,t)e^{ix\cdot\xi}\,d\xi=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}Ce^{-i|\xi|^\beta t}e^{ix\cdot\xi}\,d\xi=\frac{C}{(2\pi)^n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{i(x\cdot\xi-|\xi|^\beta t)}\,d\xi.$$ I wonder if the function $ w (x, t) $ that I want to verify is the solution of the EDP in question has this form. It is not obvious to me. What could I do?